# How run subprocess in Python 3 on windows for convert video?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cmd, ffmpeg

I have a little problem, I have trying for a lot time converted a video with FFMPEG in python 3 like this:

The model,

```
class Video(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
   state = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
   user_email = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
   uploadDate = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
   message = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
   original_video = models.FileField(upload_to='video', null=True)
   converted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And the code of converted.

```
video = Video.objects.filter(id=param_id).get()
pathConverted = 'C:\\Users\\diego\\Documents\\GitHub\\convertido.mp4'
cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-i ', video.original_video.path, ' -b 1500k -vcodec ibx264 -g 30', pathConverted]
print('Ejecutando... ', ' '.join(cmd))
try:
    proc = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)
    proc.subprocess.wait()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
```

The error is this.

```
 raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output)) RuntimeError: command '['ffmpeg', '-i ', 'C:\\Users\\diego\\Documents\\GitHub\\video1.avi', ' -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -g 30', 'C:\\Users\\diego\\Documents\\GitHub\\convertido.mp4']' return with error (code 1): None
```

And also I have tried this:

```
video = Video.objects.filter(id=1).get()
pathConverted = 'C:\\Users\\diego\\Documents\\GitHub\\convertido.mp4'
cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-i ', video.original_video.path, ' -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -g 30', pathConverted]
print('Ejecutando... ', ' '.join(cmd))
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
proc.subprocess.wait()
```

In this case the error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] No such file or directory
```

But when I copy the path and paste this in CMD on windows for try this converted the video. It works fine.

Then, I am confused, I don't understand what is the error.

Somebody can help me please?

Comment: Have you tried to define full path to ffmpeg?

Comment: Dear Sergey, I config the path environment variable in Windows I download the "ffmpeg" and put it in C:\ffmpeg\ then, my EV in the path put C:\ffmpeg\bin\ Even, when I open the CMD and try the ffmpeg this works fine. But the error persist

Comment: You can try. If it works, it will be at least a clear cause of the error, and it will be easier to continue the search for solutions.

Comment: I have found the solution. It was simply put subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i path/.../original path/.../convertido') then, it works. thanks for your reply Sergey.

Answer (score 1):

The file not found is file "ffmpeg".
Try to enter file with path and extension : c:\Program Files\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe

Best Regard
Emmanuel

Comment: Dear Emmanuel, I config the path environment variable in Windows I download the "ffmpeg" and put it in C:\ffmpeg\ then, my EV in the path put C:\ffmpeg\bin\ Even, when I open the CMD and try the ffmpeg this works fine. :(